# Filter Array till value match

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

## I like to get  from the start of the array the records till match of first string 'red' on this example (4 first records)

```
const arrayFull = [
{id:'1' type:'blue'},
{id:'2' type:'blue'},
{id:'3' type:'blue'},
{id:'4' type:'blue'},
{id:'5' type:'red'},
{id:'6' type:'blue'},
{id:'7' type:'blue'},
{id:'8' type:'blue'},
{id:'9' type:'red'},
{id:'10' type:'red'},
];
```

## Example output needs it:

```
[ 
{id:'1' type:'blue'},
{id:'2' type:'blue'},
{id:'3' type:'blue'},
{id:'4' type:'blue'}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In a declarative fashion:

```
arrayFull.slice(0, arrayFull.findIndex((e) => e.type === "red"));
```

This works by first finding the index of the first occurrence of `type: 'red'`, and then slicing a copy of the array up to that point.

This only works correctly when there is at least one occurrence of `type: 'red'` though, because otherwise `findIndex` returns `-1`. To make it work in all situations you can check if the index is `-1`, and if true just return a copy of the original array.

Again, declaratively:

```js
const arrayFull = [{id:"1",type:"blue"},{id:"2",type:"blue"},{id:"3",type:"blue"},{id:"4",type:"blue"},{id:"5",type:"red"},{id:"6",type:"blue"},{id:"7",type:"blue"},{id:"8",type:"blue"},{id:"9",type:"red"},{id:"10",type:"red"}];

// The solution:

const firstRedIndex = arrayFull.findIndex((e) => e.type === "red");
const result = firstRedIndex === -1 ? [...arrayFull] : arrayFull.slice(0, firstRedIndex);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run a traditional `for` loop. Iterate over the items, once you find `red` break out of the loop

```js
const arrayFull = [
  { id: "1", type: "blue" },
  { id: "2", type: "blue" },
  { id: "3", type: "blue" },
  { id: "4", type: "blue" },
  { id: "5", type: "red" },
  { id: "6", type: "blue" },
  { id: "7", type: "blue" },
  { id: "8", type: "blue" },
  { id: "9", type: "red" },
  { id: "10", type: "red" }
];
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrayFull.length; i++) {
  if (arrayFull[i].type === "red") {
   break;
  } else {
   result.push(arrayFull[i]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```